# Trying to unnest broom::augment data, but R "can't cast"

Tags: r, purrr, broom

I can't reproduce the data here, but I'm hoping I'm making an obvious mistake. I am trying to get residuals from all the of the models I fit with purrr::map. My code looks like this:

```
  df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, fit_mod),
         model_data = map(model, broom::augment)) %>%
  ungroup()%>%
  unnest(c(data, model_data))
```

I get an error related to the title of one of the coefficients in my model:

> Error: Can't cast `model_data$poly.Actual_Population..2..raw...TRUE.`
>    to `model_data$poly.Actual_Population..2..raw...TRUE.` .

How can I just pull those residuals out of there? I want to check my models.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: Can you try `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest %>% mutate(model = map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data = .x)), model_data = map(model, broom::augment)) %>%  ungroup %>%  unnest(model_data) %>% select(cyl, .resid)`

Comment: Or `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest %>% transmute(resid = map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data = .x) %>% broom::augment(.) %>% pull(.resid))) %>% unnest(resid)` assuming that you are only interested in the grouping column and `resid`

Comment: Sorry, I get the same error message with these attempts to. The problem must be specific to my data.

Comment: @Nazer the problem is the `poly()` function your are using. It generates names for the coefficients which after `augment()` `unnest()` can't handle.