# broom::augment returns matrix can't unnest

Tags: r, broom

I'm trying to run broom on augment on lm(y ~poly(x, 3), data = dat).

With that formaula broom::augment returns a matrix in a nested column. When I try to unnest, this fails whit an error message similar to "can't cast poly...

I'v found a similar question, but no answer
[Trying to unnest broom::augment data, but R "can't cast"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531385/trying-to-unnest-broomaugment-data-but-r-cant-cast)

```
library(rmarkdown)
library(tidyverse)
library(fs)

structure(list(a = c("2019-11-25", "2019-11-25", 
"2019-11-25", "2019-11-25", "2019-11-25"), 
b = c("laktat-felttest", "laktat-felttest", 
"laktat-felttest", "laktat-felttest", 
"laktat-felttest"), 
c = c("kai", "kai", "kai", "kai", "kai"), 
maaling = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
load = c(800, 850, 900, 1000, 1100), 
time_mm = c(5, 5, 4, 4, 4), 
time_ss = c(9, 0, 55, 35, 45), 
hr = c(125, 140, 140, 160, 172), 
rpe = c(2, 4, 4, 8, 9), 
laktat = c(2.7, 2.1, 2, 4.8, 10.2), 
time = c(309, 300, 295, 275, 285), 
x = c(2.58899676375405, 2.83333333333333, 
3.05084745762712, 3.63636363636364, 3.85964912280702), 
la_x = c(1.042875, 0.741176470588235, 
0.655555555555556, 1.32, 2.64272727272727)), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
row.names = c(NA, -5L)) ->
dat

dat %>% 
    group_by(a,b,c) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(model = data %>% map( ., ~lm( data = ., laktat ~ poly(x, 3), na.action = "na.exclude")),
           tidied = model %>% map( ., broom::tidy ),
           glance = model %>% map(., broom::glance), 
           augment = map( model, broom::augment), 
           augment = map( augment, janitor::clean_names, "snake" )) ->
    model_tbl

##model_tbl %>% 
##    unnest(augment)
```

It seems to me, that the nested column, where augment is, there is a matrix. I don't know how to change this to listcolumns.

Greetings from Denmark
Dan Olesen

Comment: What, exactly, is your desired output?

Comment: Maybe `model_tbl$augment[[1]]`

Comment: It looks like you "solved your problem" @olesendan - can you put the code that you used as an answer or append to your question? I had a similar problem with poly, and I'm not sure what your comment below means you did.

Comment: @jessi, what is your problem? It's been some time, since I worked on this problem. But maybe I'm able to help you, if I see your code?

Comment: ```   test <- mtcars %>%
           nest(data = -cyl) %>%
           mutate(
    fit = map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ disp + poly(wt, 2), data = .x)),
    tidied = map(fit, tidy),
    glanced = map(fit, glance),
    augmented = map(fit, augment) 
    # augmented = map(augment(fit, data = .)) # fails w subscript out of bounds
  )
test %>%
  unnest(augmented) # this fails

test$augmented[[1]]# this works```

Comment: @jessi
I would use the following solution:
```
    mtcars %>% 
    nest(data = -cyl) %>% 
    mutate( fit = map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ disp + poly(wt, 2), data = .x)), 
    tidied = map(fit, tidy), 
    glanced = map(fit, glance), 
    augmented = map(fit, augment) -> 
    test_fit
test_fit %>% pivot_wider(augmented) -> 
    test_fit_wider
```
after this you can unnest the column you need.

Comment: @jessi 
ex. 
```
    test_fit_wider %>% 
    unnest_longer(col=disp) %>% 
    unnest(cols=c(-data, -fit, -tidied, -glanced, -'poly(wt, 2)'))
```

Comment: Thanks @olesendan - however, ```test_fit %>% pivot_wider(augmented)``` fails   ```Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, ".name", value = "_") : replacement has 1 row, data has 0```

Comment: @jessi. my mistake. instead of pivot'ing, it should be unnest'ing so.
test_fit %>% unnest_wider(augmented) -> test_fit_wider

test_fit_wider %>% unnest(cols=c(-data, -fit, -tidied, -glanced, -`poly(wt, 2)`))
```

Comment: Oh - yes! that works. ```unnest_wider()``` is the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `poly()` function is the problem. It causes weird column names. You can replace it by `x + I(x^2) + I(x^3)` and the you get better column names.

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(a,b,c) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(model = data %>% map( ., ~lm( data = ., laktat ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3), na.action = "na.exclude")),
         tidied = model %>% map( ., broom::tidy ),
         glance = model %>% map(., broom::glance), 
         augment = map( model, broom::augment),
         augment = map( augment, janitor::clean_names, "snake" )) ->
  model_tbl
```

Update:
I just realized an issue. Using `x + I(x^2) + I(x^3)` is not exactly the same as `poly(x, 3)`. If you use the latter the coefficients are not correlated, but if you use the first they are. Don't know how to solve this at the moment.

Comment: Hi ricoderks.
Thank you, for your answer.
I've solved my problem, for now, by un selcting the matrix before I unnest augments.

regarding poly, I've readan answer where the advise is to just raw = TRUE in poly.